# Destroying and reloading a child component

Tags: angular

I need to be able to completely reload a child component. It seems the best way to to acheive this is by using a simple `*ngIf` with a boolean value; Set false to remove the component, and then set to true to re-initialize it, ie:

```
<app-child *ngIf="enabled"></app-child>
```

However, it seems that just doing this isn't enough to quickly remove/reinitialize the component:

```
reloadTree(){
  this.enabled = false;
  this.enabled = true; // doesn't work- child ngOnInit isn't called
}
```

Rather, I have to use a `setTimeout` before it will work:

```
reloadTree(){
  this.enabled = false;
  const self = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.enabled = true;
  }, 1);
}
```

I presume this is to do with the way Angular renders templates? This isn't paricularly elegant- can anyone suggest a better way to acheive what I'm trying to do here? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to reload it in the first place. That seems like a design issue. Instead, you should probably pass it a different input, or make it react to an event emitted from an observable.

Comment: You may need to actively hit angulars change detection in between the flag toggling. This [ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) may be helpful here. Inject it and call `this.ref.detectChanges` in between.

Comment: I admit it's a bit of a hack. Not worth going into here but suffice to say I've spent days with a particular problem and this seems the only way to get around it. @BenediktSchmidt- thank you, can you elaborate?

Comment: The problem why you currently need to use the setTimeout is because angular may never notice that you've changed values at all. Therefore the DOM stays untouched and the component may not be destroyed. I'm not 100% sure cause I'm not aware of when angular detects changes, but changing a value and rechanging it in the next line may just be too quick. And the *ngIf is only updated when angular gets hold of any changes on the variable. Therefore I guess you have to manually tell angular that something has changed.

Comment: To clarify, you only want to call the ngOnInit method of your child component once the reloadTree() function is called? You can use the @ViewChild to directly call methods of your child components.

Comment: Just a thought here. Maybe you can put your init code in another function and call it from ngOnInit. Then when you want to reinitialize it you can call that function inside the `reloadTree` function. You could use ViewChild to have a reference of your child component to call the init function

Comment: Try moving what is inside your your child `ngOnInit` into `ngAfterViewInit` instead

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt, I read a few things on `ChangeDetectorRef` and followed your advice, and it works great, many thanks. If you like, you could post this as an answer in which case I'll accept, as this is a direct and solid solution to my problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions. Unfortunately in my specific case, these won't work, for various reasons. `ChangeDetectorRef` totally solves this.

Comment: Yeah for everyone else with a similar probelm it's probably better to have a complete answer that combines the problem and a possible solution instead of it all beeing elaborated in multiple comments =) good to hear that it works

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So just for the record and without trying to argue if it's a clean way to do it or not, here's how you can work around the problem with the flag toggling. The main idea is to destroy the child component and create it again afterwards, which you can do with a simple ***ngIf** flag on the child component.

If the flag is toggled to *false*, the child component is destroyed and completely removed from the DOM. Afterwards you can set it to *true* again to create a new instance (if I'm not mistaken here).

The problem in the given code and the need for the workaround with the `setTimeout` method is that angular needs to be aware of changes to react to them. In this case the toggle in two lines of code may be just too quick for angular to even get hold of a change (or maybe the compiler even removes the first line at all, so nothing is ever changed, not sure though), therefore the component is neither removed nor is a new instance created.

```
reloadTree(){
  this.enabled = false; // switching to false
  this.enabled = true; // and back to true 
  // this does not notify angular that something has actually changed
}
```

What we need to do is to manually tell angular that a value has changed. This can be done through angulars [ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) class, which can be injected into the component. In between toggling the `enabled` flag, we notify angular to look for changes, so it can react to that by removing the component completely. Then we can set it back to true to create a new instance.

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef){}

reloadTree(){
    this.enabled = false;
    // now notify angular to check for updates
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    // change detection should remove the component now
    // then we can enable it again to create a new instance
    this.enabled = true; 
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, this does the job nicely. Thanks.

Comment: Worked well .. Thank you!

Comment: awesome, this is what we called hack.

Comment: awesome, this is what we called hack.

Comment: I needed to add "this.changeDetector.detectChanges();" after setting "enabled" to true.

Answer (score -3):

The question is why are you destroying the component, i think this is the wrong way to do it, put the data that need to be reloaded into a service and notify the component via RxJS Subscriber or EventEmitter that something has changed, the update event can be triggered by other components by injecting the service into the constructor and call the trigger method.

Comment: I hear you loud and clear, and have tried doing everything you suggest, but for various reasons it's not working. This relates to Kendo UI sortable plugin with nested lists. I can't work out how to get it to recognise new data. Possibly I'm not understanding their methods, or the documentation is lacking, but I can't waste any more time with this right now. I'll just stick with the `setTimeout` if necessary...

Comment: I think your problem is Zone.js, angular use zones concept for remove overhead of handling change detection. If something runs outside the ngZone, Angular will not update the data, because change detection was not triggered, every angular task runs inside a zone when a zone finish the method oneEventDone will be called and angular will start the changeDetection (The change detection thema works out of the box, when you are working in the angular world, when you use some external stuff, you need to trigger it or run it in a new custom ngZone with (zone.run(() => {..})))

Comment: I have a similar use case: `Angular-QueryBuilder` accepts a config object on initialization but doesn't update when the config changes. The config can be changed by other controls on my form. I guess it could be solved with routing and services, but the overhead doesn't seem worth it.