# Rerender the component with *ngIf

Tags: angular

Is it possible to rerender the component on the any condition, using *ngIf? I think that I can make the timeout, about 200ms, then the component value assign to null, update component value and rerender happens. 
But is it possible to rerender without timeout and changing the value of the component?

Example:

```js
@Component({})

export class RepComponent implements OnInit {
  component: any;
  
  constructor() {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.component = this.route.snapshot.data['component'];
  }  
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="component.type === 'Text'">
<!-- ... -->
</div>

<div *ngIf="component.type === 'Image'">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

So due to example, I need that if `component.type` is 'Image', the component itself rerender with the new data.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understood your problem correctly, but you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501241/5634712) out for an example of destryoing and reinitializing a component again based on `*ngIf`

Comment: Why do you want to destroy and recrete it? What are you trying to achieve? Simply changing the state of the component should be sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet I need create unique component

Comment: If you want help, please elaborate. That doesn't mean anything to me. Explain what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

the *ngIf is already doing what you want. It destroys component's html parts from DOM when the condition is not fulfilled.

Maybe you should use the same variable you have in html in the ngOnInit?

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.component = this.route.snapshot.data[this.component.type];
  }
```

Hope this helped